# Substring parsing on lists and integers

Tags: python-3.x

Update:
Adding an "0" to sec_good if its empty fixes the problem.

I am parsing unstructured pdf's and returning a few select variables. I have run into a slight problem when I check the list for a specific pattern because each of the lists are not the same.

95% of the lists contain what I'm what I'm looking for at sec_good[0][1], but if there is nothing there, the loop obviously breaks and throws an index error. Is there a way to check if sec_good[0] is there without breaking?

For example:

```
secs = re.finadall(regex,lines)
sec_re = r"(Find the pair I'm looking for and replace the divider with --)"       
for o in secs:
    for p in o:
       if len(p) != 0:
           p = re.sub(sec_re,"--",p)
               p = p.split("--")
               print("p is %s" % p)
               print("len p is %s" % len(p))
               sec_good.append(p)
if len(sec_good) == 0: ###This works.
    sec_good.append("0") ##
if len(sec_good) >= 1:
    Section.append(sec_good[0][0])
else:
    Section.append("0")
if len(sec_good[0]) >= 2: #This is what breaks.
    Sec2.append(sec_good[0][1])
else:
    Sec2.append("0")
```

I have tried a few things including.

```
def checker(lst):
    if len(lst[0][1]) > 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Any ideas of what I'm overlooking? I am appending the second value of `sec_good` into Sec2 if "--" is found. If nothing is there, I try to append "0".

> File "C:/Users/itsme/parser.py", line 105, in 
>       if len(sec_good[0]) >= 2:
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Show the actual error for completeness.

Comment: Shouldn't `if len(sec_good[0]) >= 2:` be inside of `if len(sec_good) >= 1:`?